# Html Link references

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new to HTML and CSS and am studying as much as I can however I cannot find a good explanation for the link tag that references the CSS file and what each element means.

Can anyone advise or point me in the right direction?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="welcome" href="welcome.css.scss" />
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: @lordkain Please don't quote w3schools around here...

Comment: @mooseman - what do you use for reference material / explanation what everthing means

Comment: Not CSS, It's Sass (SCSS syntax) you should compile it before embedding the file to the web page.

Comment: @lordkain The [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Main_Page) should, in my opinion, be quoted more often.

Comment: @lordkain with re: to w3schools see - http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the link tag is an html element that is explained here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-LINK

type - the content type of link
rel - This attribute describes the relationship from the current document to the anchor specified by the href attribute
href - the anchor where the link is pointing to.

Comment: so in short 'rel' is just text for convenience, could be called anything as opposed to fundamental code? Or have I miss understood?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd imagine you should leave it in. Conventions are there for a reason and with browsers handling things differently its probably best to include it - it describes what the href is referring to. That being said I'm open to correction here.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the correct way to reference a CSS file in the `<head>` of an HTML document:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="fileName.css">
```

Comment: ok so that matches mine. Except mine says "welcome". However my guess is 'type' means what file type we are referencing. No idea what 'rel' means href I understand.

Comment: `rel` stands for `relationship`. It describes how the referenced file is related to the document it is being referenced from.